# Ruby newbie question: hashes

Tags: ruby

i have the following

```
class test
 hash={}

  def printHash 
      puts hash[1]
      puts hash[2]
      puts hash[3]
    end
end

test.new.printHash
```

this prints:

```
1 
0 
1
```

Why does this happen? how can i test whether or not i have put something in that spot of the hash? or am i missing something

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're well off the mark, but it appears to be doing *something* because `hash` is a [builtin function](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/classes/Object.html#M000651) which returns a Fixnum hashcode for the object.  When you use square brackets on a Fixnum, you get the [value of the specific bit](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/classes/Fixnum.html#M000912).  What you want to do is to create an instance variable, which starts with the sigil `@`.  Also, you have to create instance variables within a method, so we'll use the one that's called whenever an object of the class is created, `initialize`:

```
class Test
  def initialize
    @hash = {}
  end

  def printHash 
      puts @hash[1]
      puts @hash[2]
      puts @hash[3]
  end
end
```

Now you'll find this prints `nil` for all three.  To test whether a hash has a value for a specific key, you can use [`has_key?`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/classes/Hash.html#M000194).

Comment: thanks alot for all the explaination. trying to learn ruby through euler problems, and this is a bit of information i would never get from this. Thanks.

Comment: It _is_ a very good explanation.  Before tackling the Euler problems, you might try the Ruby Koans: http://github.com/edgecase/ruby_koans/tree/master

Answer (score 0):

Basically 'hash' is out of scope, what you are referencing in your printHash function is a different object altogether, normally it would be nil (a new unassigned object) but as Pesto points out 'hash' is a built in function - somewhat confusing this explanation.

By putting an '@' sign in front of the your variable and assigning it in the initialize method (which is called after 'new') it becomes available in the entire instance of your object.